# Need assistance with this SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is an example of my table. I have multiple entries on multiple rows for a given `post_id` (this is metadata for posts).

```
post_id | meta_key | meta_value
________ __________ ___________
        |          |
1       | _theDate | 2016-03-31 
1       | _email   | the@email.com
2       | _theDate | 2016-01-06 
2       | _email   | the@email.com
3       | _theDate | 2017-02-14 
3       | _email   | other@user.net
4       | _theDate | 2016-10-01 
4       | _email   | the@email.com
5       | _theDate | 2016-09-25 
5       | _email   | other@user.net
6       | _theDate | 2015-11-19 
6       | _email   | other@user.net
```

What I am trying to accomplish:

I would like to find all instances of a post with the email address `the@email.com` and the year "2016" in the metadata, and then count those individual posts to find out how many posts were written by the user `the@email.com` during the year "2016".

For the moment I have managed to find only the instances of the email address using

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_id 
FROM  metatable 
WHERE meta_value LIKE '%the@email.com%'
```

This counts the total posts for that user but ***not*** only the ones written in 2016.

Comment: Maybe search through some related questions; this is fairly straightforward stuff.

Comment: I have tried. I have been battling with this for hours! :D

Comment: SELECT post_id, count(post_id) as totalPosts FROM  metatable WHERE meta_value LIKE '%the@email.com% AND meta_value LIKE%2016%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method that uses two levels of aggregation :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT post_id
      FROM  metatable 
      WHERE (meta_key = '_email' AND meta_value = 'the@email.com') OR
            (meta_key = '_theDate' AND LEFT(meta_value, 4) = '2016')
      GROUP BY post_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT meta_key) = 2
     ) p;
```

Edit : missing a quote

Comment: missing a quote.

Comment: Does it not matter that entities might not be common to both attributes

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT t.post_id -- Replace with `SELECT count(*)` to just have the total
FROM table t
WHERE t.meta_key = '_email' AND t.meta_value = 'the@email.com' AND 
      EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM table
                WHERE post_id = t.post_id AND YEAR(meta_value) = 2016
                      meta_key = '_theDate' AND meta_value = xxx
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    metatable m1
    INNER JOIN metatable m2 ON m2.post_id = m1.post_id
WHERE
    AND m1.meta_key = _theDate
    AND m1.meta_value LIKE '2016%'
    AND m2.meta_key = _email
    AND m2.meta_value = 'the@email.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by joining the table with itself, in order to get a 'id-user-date' structured table:

```
SELECT email.post_id, email.meta_value as mail, date.meta_value as date from metatable as email
 inner join metatable as dateTable
 on email.post_id = dateTable.post_id
 and email.meta_key = '_email'
 and dateTable.meta_key = '_theDate'
```

And on that you can do what you want:

```
SELECT count(*) from metatable as email
 inner join metatable as dateTable
 on email.post_id = dateTable.post_id
 and email.meta_key = '_email'
 and dateTable.meta_key = '_theDate'
 where
 email.meta_value = 'the@email.com'
 and date.meta_value like '2016%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you would like count all where the meta_key is "_theDate" the Select will:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE YEAR(aux_meta_value) = "2016" AND meta_key = '_theDate'
```